# How to register a annotation processor with quarkus

Tags: java, annotations, quarkus

I wrote a simple annotation processor, that creates a hello world endpoint:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("br.com.govbr.service.annotations.Multitenancy")
@AutoService(Processor.class)
public final class MultitenancyAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        if (!validateAnnotationUsage(roundEnv))
            return false;

        if(!roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Multitenancy.class).isEmpty())
            generateCode();

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
        Set<String> annotations = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        annotations.add(Multitenancy.class.getCanonicalName());
        return annotations;
    }

    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
        return SourceVersion.latestSupported();
    }


    private boolean validateAnnotationUsage(RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        return true;
    }

    private void generateCode() throws FileGenerationException{
        MethodSpec getNoticias = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("getHelloWorld")
                .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                .returns(String.class)
                .addAnnotation(AnnotationSpec.builder(GET.class).build())
                .addStatement("return \"Hello World\"")
                .build();

        TypeSpec helloWorld = TypeSpec.classBuilder("HelloWorld")
                .addAnnotation(AnnotationSpec.builder(Path.class).addMember("value", "\"hello\"").build())
                .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                .addMethod(getNoticias)
                .build();

        JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder("br.com.govbr.generated", helloWorld).build();

        try {
            javaFile.writeTo(processingEnv.getFiler());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            final String errorMessage = "Fail to generate class HelloWorld";
            super.processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Kind.WARNING, errorMessage);
            throw new FileGenerationException(errorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

I used this implementation in a **quarkus** project, importing with maven, i tried including the **optional** flag to see if anything changed. After checking if any code was being generated i couldn't find any evidence of it, *could anyone help me understand why the processor is not running ?*

Comment: Hi! I ran into the same issue, have you been able to solve it? It should be possible, see [https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-quarkus]. I have not yet been able to figure out the correct solution.

Comment: Ha! Just solved it. For me the problem was that I had a typo in the path to src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor...